# Why can't I display the contents of this API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to display the contents of this API http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.psc_leader_hit_hr_dist.bam?season=2015&game_type=%27D%27&game_type=%27L%27&game_type%27W%27&game_type=%27F%27&min_hip_count=15 but I keep getting an error that says:

```
  TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function

  20 | render() {
  21 |     return (
  22 |         <ul>
> 23 |             {this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.result}</li>)}
  24 |         </ul>
  25 | 
  26 |     );
```

This code below is the code to try to display the contents of the API.  I know the API starts out with `{}` but in `state = {persons: []` I used `[]`.  This won't work out because this API starts with curly brackets.  How can I make it so that that I can use `{}` (curly brackets) successfully with `map()` function in order to display contents of this API?  What am I doing wrong?

Here's `Data.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Data extends Component {

    state = {
        persons: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.psc_leader_hit_hr_dist.bam?season=2015&game_type=%27D%27&game_type=%27L%27&game_type%27W%27&game_type=%27F%27&min_hip_count=15')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({persons: res.data});
                console.log(res);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.result}</li>)}
            </ul>

        );
    }
}

export default Data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial `persons` state is an object, and objects don't have a `map` method. Default it to an array instead.

You also need to access the array in the response at `res.data.psc_leader_hit_hr_dist.queryResults.row`:

```
class Data extends Component {
  state = {
     persons: []
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.psc_leader_hit_hr_dist.bam?season=2015&game_type=%27D%27&game_type=%27L%27&game_type%27W%27&game_type=%27F%27&min_hip_count=15')
       .then(res => {
         this.setState({ persons: res.data.psc_leader_hit_hr_dist.queryResults.row });
       });
   }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Got it!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As the response is a json object you have to parse it first using JSON.parse()